# fine the div with an id that exists in an id strings

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a codeigniter project where i have to get a the id of a div and remove the class attribute of this div. Actually the id attribute of this div has to be found in an ids string. 
How can i get a div with an id that exists in ids string and remove the class attribute from that div,suppose i have an id strings as:

```
var ids = 1,2,3,4,5,6 

<div id="1" class="someclass"></div>
<div id="2" class="someclass"></div>
<div id="3" class="someclass"></div>
<div id="4" class="someclass"></div>
<div id="5" class="someclass"></div>
<div id="6" class="someclass"></div>
```

anyone help me please ??

Comment: that's not a string, do you mean `var ids = "1,2,3,4,5,6"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
var ids = "1,2,3,4,5,6";
var idsArray = ids.split(","); 
jQuery.each(idsArray, function() {
      $("#" + this).removeClass("someclass");
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can manipulate the string to make it a valid selector for multiple ids by adding a `#` to every value. Then you select those items and remove the class:

```
var ids = "1,2,3,4,5,6";

ids = '#' + ids.replace(/,/g, ',#');

$(ids).removeClass('someclass');
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/Q3Ban/)

Comment: what if he has 30 or 40 id's... what happens if he as to update it twice a day, do we have to update the array too...

Comment: @BharatSoni I'm not sure what you mean with the array. There's no array in the question. The OPs says he has a string with IDs and he wants to remove the class from all elements that has this id. This is exactly how this thing works. If this string contains forty ids or a hundred it doesn't matter.

Comment: by array I meant your string array(`ids`)... I wanted to ask if this guy has a lot of ids so do we have to update `string ids` too

Comment: I think that the string is given (maybe coming from a database or from a script). There's no need to manipulate the string on the JavaScript side and its not requested in the OP. I hope I got your question right. :)

Comment: yes, this string of ids is dynamic and comes from database. thanks to all.

Comment: @insertusernamehere but still I don't this the way u do it.. everybody has their opinions :).

Comment: @BharatSoni There are as always several ways to solve this. The accepted answer e.g. is perfectly fine too.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    var arr = [ "one", "two", "three", "four", "five" ];

    jQuery.each(arr, function() {
      $("#" + this).removeClass("yourclassname");
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all

`ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").`

if you still wanna do that you can do:

1. if you want to remove all classes then:

   `$('#yourID').on('click',function(){
       $(this).attr('class','');
     });`
2. if you want to remove a `particular-class` then:

   `$('#yourID').on('click',function(){
        $(this).removeClass('particular-class');
    });`

id you don't wanna use click event just use it directly...

Comment: Your first statement is true for HTML4 but not for HTML5: "*The value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree **and must contain at least one character. The value must not contain any space characters.***". From w3.org [3.2.3.1 The id attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute)

Comment: @insertusernamehere here it is not specified which version is used :)

Comment: True that. It wasn't also meant in an offend way, more as a side note.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
     <script>
        var ids = "1,2,3,4,5,6"; 
        var arr = ids.split(',');

        jQuery.each(arr, function() {
          $("#" + this).removeClass("yourclassname");
       });
    </script>
```